# Use subquery from select clause in where clause

Tags: sql, oracle, select, where-clause

I'm writing a query in Oracle SQL and I want to use the result from a subquery in the select clause in the where clause. The custom column sets the value using a case expression.
Simple example:

```
select 
 column_x,
 column_y,
 (case when (select something from table_x) > 1
  then 'Yes' else 'No') "yesno",
 column_z
from
 example_table
where
 yesno = 'Yes'
```

What could be the approach to achieve this, if it's even possible?
Thanks.

Comment: In this exact case you may hard code `'yes'` in the select list and move the condition to the `where` clause.

Answer (score 2):

Your query is basically fine assuming that the subquery returns no more than 1 row.  But you cannot use the column in a subquery.  You could, however, move the logic to the `from` clause:

```
select t.column_x, t.column_y, x.yesno, t.column_z
from example_table t left join
     (select case when something > 1 then 'Yes' else 'No' end as yesno
      from table_x
     ) x
     on 1=1
where x.yesno = 'Yes';
```

If the query is really a correlated subquery, then you can use `left join lateral`.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
select 
 column_x,
 column_y,
 yesno,
 column_z
from (
  select 
   column_x,
   column_y,
   (case when (select something from table_x) > 1
    then 'Yes' else 'No') yesno,
   column_z
  from
   example_table
)
where
 yesno = 'Yes'
```

Note: I removed your double quotes from `"yesno"` as they force the column name to be case-sensitive, which is undesirable.

Of course, in this example you could also do this:

```
select 
 column_x,
 column_y,
 'Yes' yesno,
 column_z
from
 example_table
where
 (select something from table_x) > 1
```